# Bash script - ввод кода

Tags: linux, bash

Всем доброго времени суток.Написал Bash скрипт для установки пакета на linux но после установки нужно активировать приложение на компьютере командой activate thisapp123,отправляю команду,после чего в терминале появляется "Enter activation code:" и мигающий белый квадрат,если вводить код руками в терминале он не отображается.

Подскажите пожалуйста что прописать в bash скрипте что бы код из него активировался, echo "код" не срабатывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй expect https://habr.com/ru/companies/ruvds/articles/328436/

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn activate thisapp123
expect "Enter activation code:"
send -- "HSEC-3М2-IPC100-FW-SP1Y\r"
expect eof
```